# Puppetersharp Proxy Issue on IIS

Tags: iis, proxy, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp, http-status-code-407

While hosting an application that we use Puppeteersharp on IIS, I get a 407 error. I make the relevant proxy settings, but I still keep getting the same error.
[image]

I tried each of the settings in the picture, but the result did not change. I'm sure the username and password are correct.

When I run the application exe, it goes to the internet without being connected to the proxy, but IIS does not come out either.

How do i solve this problem?

Comment: This is probably caused by the account that IIS is running under not having the appropriate permissions to get through the authenticating proxy. You could either give the IIS user permissions to get through the proxy, or configure your application to run as a network user with permissions to get through the proxy. This can be done by either getting IIS to run as a domain user, or by configuring you application to run as a domain user using web.config.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. This is probably caused by the puppeteersharp library that is running under your project. The library may be going to another url to configuration some settings. So the proxy server may be blocking these urls. You can detect this url and allow it. I couldn't solve the problem then i changed my library as selenium. This solve my problem in IIS.

Comment: So are you saying that you don't know, but using Selenium works and to use that? Or what solved your problem in IIS?

Comment: Yes. I don't know how to solve this IIS and puppettersharp proxy problem. But i changed my nuget as selenium instead of puppeteersharp then i host my application in iis. This method solve my same problem. I tried to change the permissions of the iis user but it didn't work or I could not change the permission settings of the iis user.